# Force http on specific folder and maintain https on all others

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I have a site as follows https://domain.com/app/ the site has a folder that houses web services. The path to which is https://domain.com/app/ws/api.php All this works fine, however I want the web service path to be http and not https (remove https from api calls) How can I achieve this? my htaccess is as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: https is served from a different port than http - you may have to alter the server configuration to do this, and set up two `VirtualHost` entries.

Comment: Create a new <VirtualHost *:80> for the  http path? would you mind elaborating

Comment: Using site configuration or .htaccess ?